# What is the best way to recover from a connection failure in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, windows, service, communication, mysql-5.7

**Background:**  This question follows up on 2 other questions I’ve posted here in the past week.  In a 2-3 week process of learning MySQL and attempting to get a Python stock info scrapping program to feed data into a MySQL schema (database, table) I’m having serious difficulties with connections.  I believe I’ve now uncovered the source of my problems.  It appears that something is happening during the communication process between my Python script and the MySQL table.  I’ll be looking into this further; however, in the meantime, after running the Python script I refreshed the MySQL table to confirm that the data had been written successfully; at that point I got the message that the communication link to the database had cratered.  Checking Windows services showed that the appropriate service was stopped.  Attempting to restart the windows service resulted in

1. Message saying the service was starting, followed by
2. Message saying “start pending” followed by
3. Message saying “service stopped. (I’m writing this from memory, so the wording will not be exact)

I spent 20-30 minutes trying various restart method from within Workbench and focusing on the Windows service to no avail.  Finally, I did a full restart on my computer after closing all open applications.  After the full restart, everything was back to normal.  The MySQL windows service was “running” and communication was reestablished to the MySQL database.

So, The real question is:
**Is shutting down my computer and restarting the only way to reestablish communications or is there a less drastic method?**

My setup parameters are pretty vanilla with the exception that I’m putting the MySQL program on my D: drive as opposed to the C: drive (an SSD reserved for the operating sys).

**System:** Windows 8 64bit on a Xeon Ivy Bridge processor, large SSD’s, large HD’s, mucho RAM, dual X-fired video cards, ASUS Sabertooth MB (self-built a yr ago)

**Software:** MySQL 5.7, complete installation except for module for Visual Basic and Python3 (running 2.7).  Attempting to use the above hardware as both a server & client.

TIA, Doug

**Partial Logs added**  The last few entries for both.

from MySQL.err

```
2013-11-13T02:05:27.793705Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-11-13T02:05:27.793705Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-11-13T02:05:27.793705Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-11-13T02:05:28.199955Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-11-13T02:05:28.199955Z 0 [Note] D:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.2-m12-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2013-11-13T02:28:05.919396Z 1 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2013-11-13T02:28:23.592157Z 4 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2013-11-13T04:50:05.102535Z 2 [Note] Aborted connection 2 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2013-11-13T04:50:05.102535Z 5 [Note] Aborted connection 5 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

From MySQL.log

```
2013-11-11T23:17:49.240559Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-11-11T23:17:49.240559Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-11-11T23:17:49.241559Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-11-11T23:17:49.252567Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-11-11T23:17:49.253567Z 0 [Note] D:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.2-m12-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2013-11-11T23:18:44.161120Z 2 [Note] Aborted connection 2 to db: 'mysql' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2013-11-11T23:18:44.161120Z 1 [Note] Aborted connection 1 to db: 'mysql' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2013-11-11T23:23:42.738555Z 4 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2013-11-12T01:32:37.841648Z 5 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2013-11-12T01:33:17.269224Z 8 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2013-11-12T03:59:44.116187Z 6 [Note] Aborted connection 6 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2013-11-12T03:59:44.117186Z 9 [Note] Aborted connection 9 to db: 'tutorial' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2013-11-12T10:19:52.316073Z 18 [Note] Aborted connection 18 to db: 'tutorial' user: 'Doug' host: 'ISAAC' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2013-11-12T11:43:28.296173Z 20 [Note] Aborted connection 20 to db: 'tutorial' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
```

Comment: MySQL Server 5.7 is still in beta...if that far... is there a reason you are not using 5.6?  Also, there is a log of errors, typically called (hostname).err in your "datadir" (if you aren't sure where that is, run this query: show global variables like 'datadir';) that you will want to read.  See anything interesting, there? No, you should not have to reboot your machine.

Comment: Michael  I've redirected the logs to a "safe" directory on my D: drive.  Unfortunately this brings up 2 other issues which I've been kind of ignoring.  1.  The time stamp on the log files did not make any sense as installed so I added default-time-zone=SYSTEM under the [mysqld] section in the my.ini file.  The times still don't make sense. Right day, odd hours.  Item 2:  The my.ini file is placed in D:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7 on installation.  I've read that it should be in D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7, and also in C:\Windows.  I've made sure my PATH points to all. cont.

Comment: Continued:  I've placed the exact same my.ini file in all three places.  Other issue:  Usually I don't install beta versions ... wasn't aware that I did this time ... if so ...BAD ME! Thanks for catching that.  As to the logs:  yes I've been studying them.  I'll attempt to add key parts of them to my original question (above).

Comment: If your system's clock is "right" but your system clock' s time zone is wrong, that might be the clock problem.  MySQL installer for Windows has seemed screwy & inconsistent for a long time, and I don't really know what they must be thinking at Oracle :(.  Where the config file should be is "somewhere the server is looking" probably not a "path" issue; a hack be sure: put something invalid in the file and if the server starts anyway, it isn't reading that file. Sorry not too helpful, I run dozens of Linux machines, a few solaris, and I had a party when I decommissioned my last Windows server.

Comment: Wow, that was fast!  Haven't seen anything wrong (yet) with my system time or time zone.  The partial logs I added above came from my.ini # Error Logging.
log-error ="D:\ProgramData\MySQL_Logs\MySQL.err" and general-log=0
general_log_file="D:\ProgramData\MySQL_Logs\MySQL.log"   Trust I haven't been too creative.  Good idea about the "false" info in the my.ini file (one at a time).  Directing a log file to a "special" folder should do the trick.

Comment: The Z in the timestamps indicates that they should be getting written in UTC, so that part is probably good if the timestamps make sense in that light.  The errors in your logs that you see if/when the server becomes unresponsive or won't restart will be the most informative.

Comment: The timestamps are definitely UTC.  I'm mulling over switching to 5.6; have been working on the Python side today, so not much SQL work.  I'm pretty sure (80%) the my.ini file that gets read is in the ProgramData tree.  Not 100% certain of that though.